# Spring AOP get method parameter value based on parameter name

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Is it possible to get the method parameter value based on parameter name in Spring AOP.

```
MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();

Method method = signature.getMethod();

method.getParameters().getName() 
// possible to get the paramater names
```

This approach will get parameter names, not value.

```
proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()
```

will return values not names

Then is it possible to get the value based on a parameter name?

Answer (score 12):

As I searched everywhere does not exist a function that gives parameter value by name and I wrote a simple method that makes this work.

```
public Object getParameterByName(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, String parameterName) {
    MethodSignature methodSig = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();
    Object[] args = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();
    String[] parametersName = methodSig.getParameterNames();

    int idx = Arrays.asList(parametersName).indexOf(parameterName);

    if(args.length > idx) { // parameter exist
        return args[idx];
    } // otherwise your parameter does not exist by given name
    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 8):

I searched for the same thing when I had to use AOP for logging function arguments and their values but it seems there is no direct way to get value based on argument name.

What I noticed however us that value returned by `method.getParameters().getName()` and `proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()` was always in sync., i.e., for function

```
public void foo(String a, String b)
```

called as

```
foo("hello", "world");
```

`method.getParameters().getName()` returned ["a", "b"] and `proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()` returned ["hello", "world"], in order. So you can iterate over the array by index and for each index `i`, the i'th argument name would correspond to i'th argument value.

I couldn't find a supporting documentation for this behavior but hey, this code has been running on production servers for about an year it never has produced incorrect result. Though I'd be glad if someone can link to a documentation of this behavior. You may even dig into reflectiion's code to verify this behavior.